# what is the behavior of parameters of overloaded functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I was messing around with typescript function overloading and found that it has a strange behavior.

In this case, the body parameter is `undefined` in the first case but shows properly in the second.

```js
/**
 * static
 */
function backendFetch(
    method: string,
    path:string, 
    body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
):number

/**
 * parametrized
 */
function backendFetch(
    method: string,
    path:string, 
    params: { [key: string]: string | undefined },
    body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
):number


function backendFetch(
    method: string,
    path:string, 
    params?: { [key: string]: string | undefined },
    body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
):number{
    console.log('body:', body);
    return 0;
}

const body = {'foo':'test'}

// static call
backendFetch('get','/create',body);
// parametrized
backendFetch('get','/{spaceId}',{'spaceId':'test'},body);
```

the output is:

```
[LOG]: "body:",  undefined 
[LOG]: "body:",  {
  "foo": "test"
}
```

any idea why? and how to resolve this to get the `body` parameter in both cases?

Comment: Javascript (and therefore, Typescript) doesn't support binding arguments to parameters by name - if you pass three arguments then they will be bound to the first three parameters. There is another problem with your function: if the function is called with three arguments, there is no way to tell if the third argument was meant to be `body` (in the first overload) or `params` (in the second overload). Basically you are creating many problems for yourself by not just having a single signature with `params` as an optional parameter after `body`.

Comment: @kaya3 in practice overload resolution will prefer the first matching signature, meaning that the third argument will end up being `body`.  But it definitely is confusing.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, but that means there is no sense in `body` being optional in the second overload signature, because the second overload signature can never be selected unless that fourth argument is provided. So the compiler will choose the first overload because that's what it's designed to do, but there's no way to know if that's what the programmer intended when they called the function with three arguments.

Comment: @kay3 I agree completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript doesn't track the name of your parameters in overloads, it's the *positions* that matter. In fact at runtime, the overloads are removed entirely. Overloads exists only to provide more specific types for certain patterns of arguments.

Your implementation still must handle all possible argument signatures and do *everything* as if the overloads didn't exist at all.

That means that you implementation function must be directly callable according to how you are actually calling it.

And right now, it isn't.

So with this signature:

```
function backendFetch(
    method: string,
    path:string, 
    params?: { [key: string]: string | undefined },
    body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
)
```

And this call:

```
backendFetch('get','/create', body);
```

Then `body` is taking the spot of the third argument, what you call `params`.

The only reason you don't get a type error is that `params` and `body` have the same type so Typescript doesn't notice that you passed a `body` where it's expecting a `params`.

---

To make this work, your implementation could look like this:

```
function backendFetch(
    method: string,
    path:string, 
    paramsOrBody?: { [key: string]: string | undefined },
    body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
):number{
    const realParams = body ? paramsOrBody : undefined
    const realBody = body || paramsOrBody

    console.log('body:', realBody);
    return 0;
}
```

Your implementation has to support ALL overload signatures, so it check to see if there is a fourth argument and then reinterprets the meaning of those arguments in that case.

Lastly, keep in mind there are a lot of ways you could shuffle the arguments around. You could use a `...rest` parameter instead and check its length. Or you could make `body` always be the third argument, and have `params` be the optional fourth (in which case you you may not need overloads at all). But it's up to you where to go from here now that you know what is going on.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=22&pc=1#code/LAKA9AVBoAQTBnALgQyQSwMawmUAzAVwDtMMB7YmAIxUwGsBTYgEwDFGlMALAClhiCAtp27kWALkRIATumIBzADQDBABzTcJyOYqUxVNcQE8A-FIDeMANpNjUnfIUBdB7KcwAPjBItG+eUYWGABfUABKCWJCIWpGGVBQSGgQOBgNGRQRdwAvIJw8ECJSCipaBmZ2Th5+VMEYbLFJaV1lQw0kLUc9Azr1FEyhBEsbOzdW1xaPb19-QOCQlT6jFjMR20Z7KcVJ7oUvH1Y54iDQiKiYuISQRKKSMnRKGjomVg4uPkNG8XGnJfr0pptO4eu0BlkEAB5GQAIRM5hgVg2Wz2uxB+xmRwCJwW-3q1Hh6zG2xcv0UB1m2NOYRAkWisXiFkMmEoyBgMkYKAANgAFcFDGAAXhWxhgpkBgyhsJMMCklPmzNZSHZnK5cNWQpFXm8GQh0PVxluAJZxAQ5C5jAAdFzyApeAByAmrCT2-Qc7kG8IAbkMHKQhBkVAADD6QDTQCa2U7RcKLPb8ORyPaXUhGMh7eHwGBpGgsDBMNyuaByq8qh8HQpOK77WBMO7U66Rd7bmBs7rsnI8ixiy9Ku8avbK0hq2ALAgNJhGABJFghV1x8d0acsZP21PpxbR71AA)

Comment: I was looking into a solution like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoljLw) (which ends up not even needing overloads).  It might be useful to mention that [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are purely for the compiler's benefits, and that at runtime there is only the function *implementation*.  Since the call signatures that distinguish `params` from `body` are erased  from the emitted JavaScript, the implementation can't use them and has to rely on argument position, just like all other function calls in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah this could be accomplished without overloads, but it does make consuming the API a bit muddier as you get a much more complex type when interrogating the function in your IDE. There's always tradeoffs.

Comment: Do you?  In my IDE it displays `backendFetch()` as if it's an overloaded function like `1/2 backendFetch(method: string, path: string, body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined; } | undefined): number;` and `2/2 backendFetch(method: string, path: string, params: { [key: string]: string | undefined; }, body?: { [key: string]: string | undefined; } | undefined): number`.  But sure, the overloads can stay, I just noticed that refactoring into a rest union tuple eliminated the need for them.  But this is academic anyway because your answer is great

Comment: Once you are using _one_ of the overloads though, you get this: https://imgur.com/a/lQSzNpR. I'm not really making a recommendation here, but it's a factor to think about in your API design. If this is a private internal method I may not worry about it much, but if this will be documented as a public API for third parties to consume, the clarity overloads may have some merit.

Comment: Oh yeah I can add that to the list of things at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42987

Answer (score 0):

as [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne) pointed out: Typescript doesn't track the name of your parameters in overloads, it's the positions that matter.

However, since it differs in only trailing parameter, I don't think it is necessary to define overload for it.

In any case, you should keep your parameters positions intact in overloads, like so:

```
// Don't
function f1(p1:Number, p2?:String): void;
function f1(p1:Number, p3:String, p2?:String): void;

// Do
function f1(p1:Number, p2?:String): void;
function f1(p1:Number, p2?:String, p3:String): void;
function f1(p1:Number, p2?:String, p3:String): void {
    console.log({p1, p2, p3});
}

// Better yet - since it is just a trailing parameter, don't overload at all
function f1(p1:Number, p2?:String, p3?:String): void {
    console.log({p1, p2, p3});
}
```

As a bonus, if you really don't want to care about where you put your parameters, then you can just use destructured parameters:

```
type DynamicKeyedObj = { [key: string]: string | undefined };
type BaseType = { method: string, path: string };
// dividing type just for the sake of it
type Overload = BaseType & { params?: DynamicKeyedObj, body?: DynamicKeyedObj };

function f1({method, path, body, params}:Overload): void {
    console.log({method, path, params, body})
};

f1({method: 'post', path: '/', body: { something: 'yes' }});
f1({method: 'get', path: '/:id', params: {id: '123'}});
f1({method: 'post', path: '/:id', params: {id: '123'}, body: { something: 'yes' }});
```